# How to export time series from Netlogo using the time extension

Tags: r, csv, time, time-series, netlogo

I am using Netlogo and I would like to use the [time extension](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/) by Colin Sheppard to export automatically data generated by my model as time series, so that it will look like  [this](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/blob/master/examples/time-series-with-variable-time-steps.csv).

Normally, one could export all data by using `export-all-plots`, but the data are not well sorted for later use in R.

Unfortunately, I do not understand well the documentation (available [here](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/#time-series-tool)) about how to export data generated by the model into a .csv file as the documentation describes only how to load existing data into the model.

Does somebody has experiences about how to export files as time series from Netlogo or understand the documentation linked above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might it be adequate to your needs to use BehaviorSpace to export the data (in table format), with the current time as one of the metrics?  This will give you a CSV file with the time (and your other metrics) reported each tick.

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you for your answer. Is there a way to use BehaviourSpace via commandline?

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#advanced), thank you anyway.